# Placeholders in keras?

Tags: keras

```
cost=keras.losses.mean_squared_error(fin_out[:,:1000,:],epoch_y[:,:1000,:])
```

So the fin_out I am defining like this :

```
fin_out=keras.activations.sigmoid(rnn_out)

model = Model(inputs=main_input, outputs=rnn_out)

rnn_out=keras.layers.Dense(513,
    kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',activation='sigmoid')(output)
```

`rnn_out` is the output of my last layer.

`epoch_y` is the ground truth array that is been generate inside my epoch and training loop.

So when I write : `model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss=cost)`

outside that loop where `epoch_y` is generating iteratively. It says `epoch_y` is not defined , which it must say of course.

So how to toggle this problem??

Can we define a placeholder of the same dimension as `epoch_y` and put it inside cost and assign epoch_y to that placeholder.

So how can we do that placeholder thing in keras??

or Any other suggestion??

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

In `model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=cost)`, `cost` should a `callable`, basically a function that takes `y_true` and `y_pred` as arguments, see [here](https://keras.io/losses/).

So you need to give `cost=keras.lossses.mean_squared_error`

If you want to give a custom loss function, you should do like this:

```
def custom_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true[:, :1000, :], y_pred[:, :1000, :])

# use custom function for loss 
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=custom_squared_error)
```